# installing gnome desktop lightdm without selecting

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I am writing bash script to install gnome desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

But it is stuck when it ask to select between 1. lightdm and 2. gdm3.

How can I make it automated ? I want to finish the installation without any command input. Everything should be in script.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set an environment variable to skip the dialogue.

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

But you might have to take care of the configuration file on your own. E.g. configure `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

Comment: Can I do 
"
sudo sh -c 'echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager'
"
to make it default display manager ?

Comment: `sudo echo "/usr/sbin/lightdm" > /etc/X11/default-display-manager` should do the trick. But I think it is save to also update the `dpkg` database with: `echo "set shared/default-x-display-manager lightdm" | debconf-communicate`